# Wordpress Override Jquery Issue

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, wordpress, wordpress-theming

**Basically This is Exactly What I'm doing:**

**When I do this on functions.php it doesn't work**

```
//functions.php
add_action('init', 'override_jquery');

function override_jquery() {
    if( !is_admin()){
        wp_deregister_script('jquery');
        wp_enqueue_script( 'nashgraphics_jquery_library', get_template_directory_uri() . '/bootstrap/js/jquery-1.9.0.min.js');
    }
}
```

**When I do this on as a plugin it works**

```
//my_plugin.php
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'override_jquery');

function override_jquery() {
    $plugin_location=WP_PLUGIN_URL.'/'.str_replace(basename( __FILE__),"",plugin_basename(__FILE__));
    if( !is_admin()){
        wp_deregister_script('jquery');
        wp_enqueue_script( 'nashgraphics_jquery_library', $plugin_location . 'fancybox/library/jquery-1.9.0.min.js');
    }
}
```

my problem is I need to override the JQuery library throught functions.php because I'm trying to develop my own theme that requires a different version of jquery

and not override the jquery library as a plugin because that will be a serious problem if I disable the plugin.

can someone explain me why it doesn't include the jquery library when I'm doing it in functions.php while it works when I do it as a plugin?

Comment: are you using a child theme?

Comment: nope I'm trying to make a parent theme

Answer (score 0):

You didn't name the `jquery` script again. Try this:

```
function override_jquery() {
    if( !is_admin()){
        wp_deregister_script('jquery');
        wp_register_script( 'jquery', get_template_directory_uri() . '/bootstrap/js/jquery-1.9.0.min.js');
        wp_enqueue_script('jquery');
    }
}
```

You should note that it is not recommended to do use your own jQuery in WordPress. Read [this](http://eamann.com/tech/dont-dequeue-wordpress-jquery/) and [that](http://pippinsplugins.com/why-loading-your-own-jquery-is-irresponsible/).